# IReport Designer problems running with JDK 8

Tags: java, java-8, ireport

When I try to run `ireport_w.exe` from the command window, I get:

> The current path is: C: \ Java \ jdk1.8.0
>
> Java HotSpot (TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize = 512m; support was removed in 8.0.

What should I do to run iReport Designer with JDK 8?

Answer (score -1):

In general you may ignore this warning at least until Java-9. It warns you that this option became useless and may lead to the error in newer Java versions. In Java-8 PermGen was replaced with Metaspace which is more flexible in terms of memory usage, so you rarely need to tune its size explicitly.

If you still aware, you can find `ireportpro.conf` file in the iReport installation folder and remove `-J-XX:MaxPermSize=512m` part. The warning should disappear after that.